# Convert from MySQL query result or LIST to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, scala, playframework, anorm

I am using anorm with play-scala and have execute queries using:

```
val result = SQL("SELECT * FROM users)()
```

What I have been doing is the following:

```
 val queryResult = SQL(query)().map(result =>
  result.asList
  ).toList
```

However, I have realized that instead of converting it to a list, I want to actually receive JSON. Since I may change the query, I would like the ability for a JSON serializer that takes in any result and understands the column names and convert them and the results into JSON.

EDIT: 
I'm using play 2.3.10 with scala version 2.11.6.
I'm trying to map the SqlResult's metadata column names to an object or rather a json parser. I was able to get the SqlResult's metadata as

```
List(MetaDataItem(ColumnName(x),false, java.lang.Integer), MetaDataItem(ColumnName(y),.....
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to give more details.Which versions are you using, what is the schema of the table.P.S. `SQL(..)()` aka `SimpleSql.apply` is deprecated.

Comment: You must use anorm parsers but parse to Json objects [Anorm, simple SQL data access](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Getting-a-more-complex-result). For example str("name") ~ int("population") map { case n ~ p => Json.obj("name" -> n, "population" -> p) }