# What is the most elegant way to stream the results of an SQL query out as JSON?

Tags: json, playframework, anorm, playframework-2.5

Using the Play framework with [Anorm](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm), I would like to write a Controller method that simply returns the results of an SQL query as JSON. I don't want to bother converting to objects. Also, ideally this code should stream out the JSON as the SQL ResultSet is processed rather than processing the entire SQL result before returning anything to the client.

```
select colA colB from mytable
```

**JSON Response**

```
[{"colA": "ValueA", "colB": 33}, {"colA": "ValueA2", "colB": 34}, ...]
```

I would like to express this in Scala code as elegantly and concisely as possible, but the examples I'm finding seem to have a lot of boiler plate (redundant column name definitions). I'm surprised there isn't some kind of SqlResult to JsValue conversion in Play or Anorm already.

I realize you may need to define **Writes[]** or an **Enumeratee** implementation to achieve this, but once the conversion code is defined, I'd like the code for each method to be nearly as simple as this:

```
val columns = List("colA", "colB")
db.withConnection { implicit c =>
  Ok(Json.toJson(SQL"select #$columns from mytable"))
}
```

I'm not clear on the best way to define column names just once and pass it to the SQL query as well as JSON conversion code. Maybe if I create some kind of implicit ColumnNames type, the JSON conversion code could access it in the previous example?

Or maybe define my own kind of **SqlToJsonAction** to achieve even simpler code and have common control over JSON responses?

```
def getJson = SqlToJsonAction(List("colA", "colB")) { columns =>
 SQL"select #$columns from mytable"
}
```

The only related StackOverflow question I found was: [Convert from MySQL query result or LIST to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484282/convert-from-mysql-query-result-or-list-to-json), which didn't have helpful answers.

I'm a Java developer just learning Scala so I still have a lot to learn about the language, but I've read through the Anorm, Iteratee/Enumeratee, Writes, docs and numerous blogs on Anorm, and am having trouble figuring out how to setup the necessary helper code so that I can compose my JSON methods this way.

Also, I'm unclear on what approaches allow Streaming out the Response, and which will iterate the entire SQL ResultSet before responding with anything to the client. According to [Anorm Streaming Results](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#streaming-results) only methods such as fold/foldWhile/withResult and Iteratees stream. Are these the techniques I should use?

**Bonus:**

In some cases, I'll probably want to map a SQL column name to a different JSON field name. Is there a slick way to do this as well?

Something like this (no idea if this Scala syntax is possible):

```
def getJson = SqlToJsonAction("colA" -> "jsonColA", "colB", "colC" -> "jsonColC")) { columns =>
 SQL"select #$columns from mytable"
}
```

Comment: I'm also open to using Slick if it's better than Anorm. But I was leaning toward Anorm because I want to write plain SQL.

Comment: You should use what's indicated in the streaming doc. What have you tried?

Comment: I think my main hangup has been on getting the initial Stream object. It looks like Anorm will have a AkkaStream object in the next release: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/pull/101

Comment: I should have focused on one question. It's not that important to avoid case classes; I just wanted to avoid them if I could.

Comment: Anorm already has an [Akka Stream module](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22anorm-akka_2.11%22)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like I just need to read through more documentation and work on piecing things together. I'm going to close this question unless anyone thinks I should leave it open. Maybe I should write a blog post on SQL Streams and JSON for people new to Play and Scala once I figure it all out.